# Sometimes method is not executed in asp.net c# when publish

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a website of auction in asp.net web forms (empty website).I have placed a countdown timer using update panel and timer control.As this is auction website there will be many users present in a single web page. Now as the timer ends of countdown timer i have call a method ,but only some of the users present in the auction page are able to execute the method while other are not.I don't know why this is so.

This works perfectly on localhost but when i publish website into server this type of problems i start facing.

Here is the code

The code inside the tick event placed inside of update panel for timer is ..

```
  protected void tm1000ms_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Application["AuctionTimer"] != null)
        {
            if (!(Application["AuctionTimer"] as CountDownTimer).TimeLeft.ToString().Equals("00:00:00"))
            {
                string rawTime = "";
                string AuctionTime = "";

                rawTime = (Application["AuctionTimer"] as CountDownTimer).TimeLeft.ToString();

                AuctionTime = rawTime.Substring(rawTime.IndexOf(":") + 1);

                int timerSec = Convert.ToInt32(AuctionTime.Substring(AuctionTime.IndexOf(":") + 1));

                lblTimer.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                lblTimer.Text = AuctionTime + "sec";
            }
            else
            {
                    startNewItemLoading(); // **This method is not executed by some users!

                if (Session["AdminID"] != null)
                {
                    // Sold the Item
                }
            }
        }
}

 private void startNewItemLoading()
{
    tm1000ms.Enabled = false; // timer for Auction is disabled.
    divItemCard.Visible = false; // Item div is disabled so new item loading can be shown 
    divnewPlayerCard.Visible = true; // Enabling the item loading div
    upPlayerCard.Update(); // refreshing update panel as both are inside same update panel
    RestartFreshStopwatch(); // After that restarting the Auction Timer Again for new Item.
}
```

Countdown Class  for timer

```
  public class CountDownTimer
{
    public TimeSpan TimeLeft;
    System.Threading.Thread thread;

    public CountDownTimer() { }

    public CountDownTimer(TimeSpan original)
    {
        this.TimeLeft = original;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (!TimeLeft.Equals(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00")))
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    TimeLeft = TimeLeft.Subtract(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:01"));
                }
            }
        });
        this.thread.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        TimeLeft = TimeLeft.Add(TimeSpan.Parse("00:00:00"));
        if (this.thread != null)
            this.thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

the startNewItemLoading method is not executing by some users but some of them are able to i don't know why but this problem starts when i publish website into server ..

Am i doing anything wrong? Please help me.

Comment: For those looking to assist, be aware the OP has deleted their last copy of the same question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62386598/sometimes-method-is-not-executed-in-asp-net-c-sharp

Comment: whats wrong with that @mjwills

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that @Anant. Just letting people know.